# Best practice for setting BindingContext for view, with multiple viewmodels?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

Let's say we have a structure like this, for a page with a viewmodel attached:

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Page
{
    public Page(PageViewModel pageViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = pageViewModel;
    }
}
```

Relevant part of the page:

```
 <Button Text="Click here" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />
```

The viewmodel, PageViewModel, has a RelayCommand with a method called "ButtonClicked".

Suppose then, that I want to add a text field, with some data from a different viewmodel, such as this XAML:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding NewList}">
<Label Text="{Binding ListItemName}" />
</CarouselView>
```

**What is the best way to add a new viewmodel? Essentially adding multiple binding contexts.**

Comment: The binding context is one. How many objects this binding context will contain however, is entirely up to you.

Comment: Can I specify multiple objects in the binding context of the constructor for Page?

Comment: You could have a parent viewmodel, with children (different types of) viewmodels. The Bindings will be either to properties on the parent or in the children (i.e. "{Binding ChildViewModel.Property}").

Comment: I wouldn't nest ViewModels to be honest @o_w it's a dirty coding practice, Your View to ViewModel is a 1-1 relationship, if you are using multiple vm's that is just bad design and you need to redesign your architecture for this View. One ViewModel can work with multiple Views but even then it should not be a Stand-alone View.

Comment: @eengstroem No. As I said, the binding context is one. It points to a single object in your memory. This single object can contain other objects. As few or as many as you need. They should be fields of your ViewModel, that you used as binding context.

Comment: @FreakyAli No. There is nothing wrong with having multiple, reusable, viewmodels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page is usually only bound to one binding context, you can set your own binding context in each child control to achieve this effect, like this:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      
    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="0"
        BindingContext="{Binding Source = {local:OneViewModel}}"/>
        <label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="1"
        BindingContext="{Binding Source = {local:TwoViewModel}}">
        <label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackLayout>

  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had in mind. For defining local, would it just be the namespace of my viewmodels?

Comment: Yes, like this `xmlns: local="clr namespace: DataBindingDemos"`

Comment: I find this easier to read: `Text = { Binding Name, Source={ local:OneViewModel } }`